# NPM install dependency problems: code EPEERINVALID

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, browserify

I have an installation problem

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "d:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "d:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bootstrap-datetimepicker" "--save
-dev"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.1
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package grunt does not satisfy its siblings' peerDepend
encies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-nodeunit@0.3.3 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-watch@0.6.1 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-jshint@0.10.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0
```

Comment: Use code markdown for formatting of code or commands.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty obvious actually, you have run into some dependency issues. The packages you are trying to install do not satisfy **grunt's** current version:

> npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-nodeunit@0.3.3 wants grunt@~0.4.0

---

As seen in both the error message and in [grunt-contrib-nodeunit](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-nodeunit)'s repo, this package requires 0.4.0:

> This plugin requires Grunt ~0.4.0

So you should simply update your **grunt** version :)